# Django save with update_fields and POSTGRESQL MVCC

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I search on internet but I don't find informations about that, if I look at Heroku Devcenter I have this information:

url: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-concurrency#disadvantages-of-mvcc

"This is why an UPDATE actually creates a new row",

So if Postgresql actually creates a new row for each update, does it make any sense to use update_fields to increase performance?

I will in a few days create a little benchmark to test if there is any performance improvement in using update_fields.

Comment: `update_fields` has its own benefits, you're actually asking does `force_update` makes sense - your text deals with the fact that `update_fields` automatically sets `force_update` (and that is the topic in linked text). Btw, don't know the answer, will wait your benchmarks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be the case that using `update_fields` will increase the performance of the PostgreSQL update operation itself. What we can say with confidence, though, is that updating a subset of the fields will improve the performance of packaging and sending data across the network, since there's less of it.

Moreover, there are good reasons to use `update_fields` that don't have anything to do with performance. It's implicitly required when you only have a subset of the fields in the first place (as with `only()` and `defer()`), and it can help avoid race conditions by reducing the risk that you'll overwrite fields that have been changed by another process.